# How to support larger tiles

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I've been working on a small platformer and decided to try new collision detection. I followed ray wenderlich's tutorial on how to make an iOS platformer and a couple of questions came up. In the tutorial its set up to support a very specific tile size and I was wondering how to modify it correctly to support a tile size of 80x80. This was the method used to get the tile coordinates and bounding boxes.

```
- (CGPoint)tileCoordForPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
    float x = floor(position.x / map.tileSize.width);
    float levelHeightInPixels = map.mapSize.height * map.tileSize.height;
    float y = floor((levelHeightInPixels - position.y) / map.tileSize.height);
    return ccp(x, y);
}

-(CGRect)tileRectFromTileCoords:(CGPoint)tileCoords
{
    float levelHeightInPixels = map.mapSize.height * map.tileSize.height;
    CGPoint origin = ccp(tileCoords.x * map.tileSize.width, levelHeightInPixels - ((tileCoords.y + 1) * map.tileSize.height));
    return CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, map.tileSize.width, map.tileSize.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this code uses the values from the tilemap, if setup correctly in the tilemap you don't need to change the code.

I certainly don't see any magic numbers, which is good. Only fools and wizards use magic numbers. :)

Comment: Thats what I assumed as well but whenever I load a tile map other than the one provided it causes a crash. It might have something to do with the hit detection instead.

Comment: If you get a crash then that's what you should be asking about. Don't assume what it might be about, that will only waste your time. Focus on the crash and why it's happening.